# Avoiding data replication while using comma separated data

Tags: mysql, replication

I am working on a project where i am required to save data in the " comma separated data" form. I need to avoid data replication here. How do I do that?

Eg:

```
id |  name |  fav     
1  |  abc  |  11,2,3,4,5,11,2
2  |  
3  |
.
.
.
```

how do i display only 11,2,3,4,5 (from fav)

I used the query:

---

SELECT DISTINCT fav
FROM user_details
WHERE id =  '1'
ORDER BY fav ASC***

Comment: When you parse the array in your application level code, filter unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by *storing* the data in a manner appropriate for a relational database and then *extracting* the data in a format appropriate for presentation.

You seem to have a need for a "UserFav" table, with one row per use and one per "fav".  If you had such a structure, your query would be:

```
select id, name, group_concat(distinct uf.favid order by uf.id) as favs
from table t join
     UserFav uf
     on t.id = uf.userid
group by t.id;
```

Attempting to do such string operations in the database is, shall I say, silly.  Databases are designed to do some very sophisticated data manipulations.  Use them.  Don't try to fit a round peg into a square hole.

Comment: (pegs square, whole round)